# Regex working in testing program but not in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a URL that looks like

```
'accommodation/destination.php?code=108459&destination=Yang+Chum+Noi'
```

The regex I'm using:

```
(^accommodation/destination\.php\?code=([0-9]+)&destination=([^/]+)$)
```

...works fine in my regex tester but when I use it in the `.htaccess` file it doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, with the help of both MatTheCat and bazmegakapa I got it to work, the {QUERY_STRING} solution was OK after I fixed my own typo, and after removing the QSA flag using the solution here http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=55432a1ab73cdf5a&hl=en it is now working, thanks again to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape slashes but the point. And RewriteRule don't care about caracters after interrogation point, so you have to use QSA flag.

But this redirection seems weird, how do you use this regexp in your htaccess ??

Comment: Yes a couple of unnecessary escapes, I'll take them out when it's working. I'm redirecting to another URL using the captured code

Comment: You forget QSA, it's not the way of a htaccess redirection which serve to hide GET parameters..!

Comment: Actually this redirection is from an old URL that uses GET parameters to a new one that does not, and is handled below the current line. I'm checking the documentation for QSA now but is doesn't seem applicable as I'm not passing the query string.

Comment: So I think you should create the 'accommodation/destination.php?code=108459&destination=Yang+Chum+Noi' page which will perform a 301 redirection with php header function.

Comment: No, there's at least 150 of these old URLs in Google's index, it has to use a regex

Comment: Isn't just GET parameters which change ?

Comment: OK, that would be a solution but the htaccess is now working, thanks for your help with the QSA flag

Answer (score 2):

<strike>^accommodation/destination.php\?code=([0-9]+)&destination=([^/]+)$</strike>

Tested on my server, it should work.

No, no, it should never work. So here is something that will work though:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=([0-9]+)&destination=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^accomodation/destination\.php$ your.php [L]
```

Comment: It should, but it isn't on my servers, development or production, other regexs are working fine on both

Comment: That looks like it should work but it's not, it's driving me crazy

Comment: Can you paste the whole rule as it is in your htaccess?

Comment: RewriteRule ^accommodation/destination\.php\?code=([0-9]+)&destination=(.+)$ http://www.example.com/accomodation-$1 [NC,R=301,L]

Comment: You should change this to the RewriteCond version, because RewriteRule will not check the query string.

Comment: Also, don't you want to use $2 in your URL?

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=([0-9]+)&destination=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^accomodation/destination\.php$ http://www.example.com/accomodation-$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Sorry, that is the one I'm using, no the first capture is the numeric ID

Comment: I don't get it... If RewriteCond and RewriteRule is in a separate line, I'm out of ideas :). Maybe I'm not drunk enough yet.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that htaccess isn't matching the regex, I'll have a drink too, see if it helps :)

Comment: Ok, it's now redirecting but appending the query string

Comment: It was a typo in my htaccess file, all fixed now, no need for more thinking fluid :)

Comment: No worries, I would have gotten drunk anyways :).